# Get payload from request redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using "redux-api-middleware" to send action to backend. I use redux to process the data received from the backend.

```
export const example_action = () => createAction({
  endpoint: 'https://expample/',
  method: 'POST',
  body: bodyExpamle
  headers: {},
  types: [
    REQUEST,
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
  ]
})
```

In order not to transfer large volumes from the frontend to the backend, and then back, I want to save its payload in the redux store when requesting, but when the reducer fires on the REQUEST type, the action contains only the type field without the payload. Tell me how to get the payload.

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUEST': {
     // HERE ACTION HAVE ONLY TYPE FIELD
    case 'SUCCESS':
      //HERE ACTION HAVE PAYLOAD
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide component where you are calling your action and a full redux code, I’m pretty sure your action can have anything as payload, however there is no way to fix your code without code

Answer (score 0):

It was found in the redux-api-middleware documentation that with each type it is possible to pass the data that is needed

```
createAction({
  endpoint: 'http://www.example.com/api/users',
  method: 'GET',
  types: [
    {
      type: 'REQUEST',
      payload: (action, state) => ({ endpoint: action.endpoint })
    },
    'SUCCESS',
    'FAILURE'
  ]
})
```